# problema al hacer insert en BD con un tipo de dato blob

Tags: java

estoy desarrollando una aplicación que gestione una clinica privada de medicina. Tengo que guardar en una BD los datos de los clientes incluyendo su fotografía, realizada con una webCam, he conseguido visualizar la webCam, he conseguido realizar la foto, pero el problema es al añadir la foto a la BD. Los insert los hace perfectamente, incluido el de la foto, pero al acceder a la BD, veo que se ha insertado un archivo con extensión ".bin" y al descargarlo, no puedo abrirlo con nada para comprobar que la foto se corresponde con la del cliente. Adjunto fuente actual, a ver si alguien me puede orientar un poco, incluso si estoy haciendo mal la subida de la imagen.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

1 código de insercción de datos.

```
public void insertarBd(){
     PreparedStatement prepared;

     String id = tfId.getText();
     String nombre = tfNombre.getText();
     String apellido1 = tfApellido1.getText();
     String apellido2 = tfApellido2.getText();
     String dni = tfDni.getText();
     Date fechaNacimiento = Date.valueOf(tfFechaNacimiento.getText());
     Date fechaAlta = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());
     String poblacion = tfPoblacion.getText();
     String direccion = taDireccion.getText();
     int codigoPostal = Integer.parseInt(tfCodigoPostal.getText());
     String provincia = tfProvincia.getText();
     int telefonoFijo = 0;
     int telefonoResponsable = 0;
     int telefonoMovil = 0;
     try{
         telefonoFijo = Integer.valueOf(tfTelefonoFijo.getText());
         telefonoResponsable = Integer.valueOf(tfTelefonoMovil.getText()); 
         telefonoMovil = Integer.valueOf(tfTelefonoMovil.getText());           
     }catch(NumberFormatException e){
         tfTelefonoFijo.setBackground(Color.red);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Solo numeros, por favor");
     }

     String nombreTutor = tfNombreTutor.getText();

     Date fechaUltimaConsulta = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());
     String consulta = tfConsulta.getText();

     tfNombreTutor.setText(tfNombre.getText());

    try {

            blob = conexion.createBlob();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(blob.setBinaryStream(1));
            oos.writeObject(imagen);
            oos.close();


        prepared = mysql.getConexion().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pacientes (id, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fechaNacimiento, "
                + "fechaAlta, poblacion, direccion, codigoPostal, provincia, telefonoFijo, telefonoMovil, nombreTutor, "
                + "telefonoResponsable, fechaUltimaConsulta, consulta, foto)"
                + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");



         // Parámetros para el preparedStatement
        prepared.setString(1,id);
        prepared.setString(2,nombre);
        prepared.setString(3,apellido1);
        prepared.setString(4,apellido2);
        prepared.setString(5, dni);
        prepared.setDate(6, fechaNacimiento);
        prepared.setDate(7,fechaAlta);
        prepared.setString(8, poblacion);
        prepared.setString(9, direccion);
        prepared.setInt(10, codigoPostal);
        prepared.setString(11, provincia);
        prepared.setInt(12, telefonoFijo);
        prepared.setInt(13, telefonoMovil);
        prepared.setString(14, nombreTutor);
        prepared.setInt(15, telefonoResponsable);
        prepared.setDate(16, fechaUltimaConsulta);
        prepared.setString(17, consulta);
        prepared.setBlob(18, blob);
        // llamada al métdo ejecuta update el cual actualiza
        //prepared.executeUpdate();

        if(prepared.executeUpdate() >= 1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Paciente insertado Correctamente");
        }

        prepared.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problema con base de datos");
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        tfCodigoPostal.setBackground(Color.red);

        tfTelefonoMovil.setBackground(Color.red);

    }catch (IOException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(VentanaFormulario.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

 }
```

2ª codigo del botón con el que hago la foto de la web cam

```
private void btCapturarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
   BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();
   imagen = new File(tfNombre.getText()+tfApellido1.getText()+".png");
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", imagen);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al Guardar la foto");
    }
}
```

Como se puede ver, uso el tipo de datos blob para añadir la imagen, y el resultado en la BD es el el archivo insertado correctamente

pero al descargarlo es un archivo.bin y no puedo abrirlo

**Actualización**
*Añado código ActionPerformed del botón guardar, que llama al método insertaBD()*

```
public void insertarBd(){
     PreparedStatement prepared;

     String id = tfId.getText();
     String nombre = tfNombre.getText();
     String apellido1 = tfApellido1.getText();
     String apellido2 = tfApellido2.getText();
     String dni = tfDni.getText();
     Date fechaNacimiento = Date.valueOf(tfFechaNacimiento.getText());
     Date fechaAlta = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());
     String poblacion = tfPoblacion.getText();
     String direccion = taDireccion.getText();
     int codigoPostal = Integer.parseInt(tfCodigoPostal.getText());
     String provincia = tfProvincia.getText();
     int telefonoFijo = 0;
     int telefonoResponsable = 0;
     int telefonoMovil = 0;

     try{
         telefonoFijo = Integer.valueOf(tfTelefonoFijo.getText());
         telefonoResponsable = Integer.valueOf(tfTelefonoMovil.getText()); 
         telefonoMovil = Integer.valueOf(tfTelefonoMovil.getText()); 

     }catch(NumberFormatException e){
         tfTelefonoFijo.setBackground(Color.red);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Solo numeros, por favor");
     }

     String nombreTutor = tfNombreTutor.getText();

     Date fechaUltimaConsulta = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());
     String consulta = tfConsulta.getText();

     tfNombreTutor.setText(tfNombre.getText());

    try { 

        /*bloque para imagen*/
        blob = conexion.createBlob();
        ObjectOutputStream oos;
         try {
             oos = new ObjectOutputStream(blob.setBinaryStream(1));
             oos.writeObject(imagen);
             oos.close();
         } catch (IOException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(VentanaFormulario.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }


        prepared = mysql.getConexion().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pacientes (id, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fechaNacimiento, "
                + "fechaAlta, poblacion, direccion, codigoPostal, provincia, telefonoFijo, telefonoMovil, nombreTutor, "
                + "telefonoResponsable, fechaUltimaConsulta, consulta, foto)"
                + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

         // Parámetros para el preparedStatement
        prepared.setString(1,id);
        prepared.setString(2,nombre);
        prepared.setString(3,apellido1);
        prepared.setString(4,apellido2);
        prepared.setString(5, dni);
        prepared.setDate(6, fechaNacimiento);
        prepared.setDate(7,fechaAlta);
        prepared.setString(8, poblacion);
        prepared.setString(9, direccion);
        prepared.setInt(10, codigoPostal);
        prepared.setString(11, provincia);
        prepared.setInt(12, telefonoFijo);
        prepared.setInt(13, telefonoMovil);
        prepared.setString(14, nombreTutor);
        prepared.setInt(15, telefonoResponsable);
        prepared.setDate(16, fechaUltimaConsulta);
        prepared.setString(17, consulta);
        prepared.setBlob(18, blob);

        // llamada al métdo ejecuta update el cual actualiza
        prepared.executeUpdate();

        if(prepared.executeUpdate() >= 1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Paciente insertado Correctamente");
        }

        prepared.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problema con base de datos");
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        tfCodigoPostal.setBackground(Color.red);

        tfTelefonoMovil.setBackground(Color.red);
    }
 }
```

**Actualización 2**
*He cambiado el método de cargar foto, y ya no dan punteros nulos ni saltan excepciones, pero no se carga la imagen desde la BD*

```
public void cargarFotoPaciente(){
    String consulta = "SELECT foto FROM pacientes WHERE id=" + "'+tfId.getText()'";

    ResultSet resultSet = mysql.ejecutaConsulta(consulta);

    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            byte[] imgBytes = resultSet.getBytes("foto");
            if (imgBytes != null) {
                ImageIcon imagenIcon = new ImageIcon(imgBytes);
                jlFoto.setIcon(imagenIcon);
            } else {
                System.out.println("El paciente tiene foto pero no se puede cargar");
            }
        }           
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al cargar la foto desde la base de datos");
    }
 }
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

*Código para arrancar la webcam*

```
webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
     webcam.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize());

     WebcamPanel panel = new WebcamPanel(webcam);
     panel = new WebcamPanel(webcam);
     panel.setFPSDisplayed(false);
     panel.setDisplayDebugInfo(false);
     panel.setImageSizeDisplayed(false);
     panel.setMirrored(true);
     panel.setSize(webcam.getViewSize());

     jpDatosPaciente.add(panel);
     pack();
     panel.setBounds(768, 50, 220, 190);
     panel.setVisible(true);
```

*Código del botón para capturar la imagen de la webcam*

```
image = webcam.getImage();
   archivo = new File(tfNombre.getText()+tfApellido1.getText() + ".png");
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", archivo);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al Guardar la foto");
    }
```

*Código de la insercción en la BD*

```
PreparedStatement prepared;

     String id = tfId.getText();
     String nombre = tfNombre.getText();
     String apellido1 = tfApellido1.getText();
     String apellido2 = tfApellido2.getText();
     String dni = tfDni.getText();
     Date fechaNacimiento = Date.valueOf(tfFechaNacimiento.getText());
     Date fechaAlta = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());
     String poblacion = tfPoblacion.getText();
     String direccion = taDireccion.getText();
     int codigoPostal = Integer.parseInt(tfCodigoPostal.getText());
     String provincia = tfProvincia.getText();
     int telefonoFijo = 0;
     int telefonoResponsable = 0;
     int telefonoMovil = 0;
     FileInputStream fis = null;

     try{
         telefonoFijo = Integer.valueOf(tfTelefonoFijo.getText());
         telefonoResponsable = Integer.valueOf(tfTelefonoMovil.getText()); 
         telefonoMovil = Integer.valueOf(tfTelefonoMovil.getText()); 

     }catch(NumberFormatException e){
         tfTelefonoFijo.setBackground(Color.red);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Solo numeros, por favor");
     }

     String nombreTutor = tfNombreTutor.getText();

     Date fechaUltimaConsulta = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());
     String consulta = tfConsulta.getText();

     tfNombreTutor.setText(tfNombre.getText());

    try { 

        /*bloque para imagen*/
        //File archivo = new File(image + tfNombre.getText() + tfApellido1.getText());
        fis = new FileInputStream(archivo);


        prepared = mysql.getConexion().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pacientes (id, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fechaNacimiento, "
                + "fechaAlta, poblacion, direccion, codigoPostal, provincia, telefonoFijo, telefonoMovil, nombreTutor, "
                + "telefonoResponsable, fechaUltimaConsulta, consulta, foto)"
                + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

         // Parámetros para el preparedStatement
        prepared.setString(1,id);
        prepared.setString(2,nombre);
        prepared.setString(3,apellido1);
        prepared.setString(4,apellido2);
        prepared.setString(5, dni);
        prepared.setDate(6, fechaNacimiento);
        prepared.setDate(7,fechaAlta);
        prepared.setString(8, poblacion);
        prepared.setString(9, direccion);
        prepared.setInt(10, codigoPostal);
        prepared.setString(11, provincia);
        prepared.setInt(12, telefonoFijo);
        prepared.setInt(13, telefonoMovil);
        prepared.setString(14, nombreTutor);
        prepared.setInt(15, telefonoResponsable);
        prepared.setDate(16, fechaUltimaConsulta);
        prepared.setString(17, consulta);
        prepared.setBinaryStream(18, fis, (int)archivo.length());

        // llamada al método ejecuta update el cual actualiza            
        if(prepared.executeUpdate() >= 1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Paciente insertado Correctamente");
        }

        prepared.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problema con base de datos");
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        tfCodigoPostal.setBackground(Color.red);

        tfTelefonoMovil.setBackground(Color.red);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(VentanaFormulario.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

*Código para mostrar la imagen de la BD*

```
String consulta = "SELECT foto FROM pacientes WHERE id=" + "'"+tfId.getText()+"'";

    ResultSet resultSet = mysql.ejecutaConsulta(consulta);
    Blob img = null;
    Image img2 = null;
    //ImageIcon icon = null;
    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            img = resultSet.getBlob("foto");
            img2 = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(img.getBinaryStream());
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img2);
            ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(jlFoto.getWidth(), jlFoto.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
            jlFoto.setIcon(icono);
        }           
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al cargar la foto desde la base de datos");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(VentanaFormulario.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Te invito a pasarte por [ask], que pongas imágenes dificulta la lectura del código.

Comment: Lo siento @Aritzbn, lo cambio en seguida

Comment: No te preocupes. :)

Comment: ¿Donde esta la parte de descargarlo?

Comment: Hola, lo descargué manualmente

Comment: ¿Has probado a renombrar el .bin como .png (suponiendo que ése fuera el formato del fichero original?

Comment: Por supuesto...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba esta forma modificada de cargar las fotos:

```
public void cargarFotoPaciente() {

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs;

    try {
        String id = tfId.getText();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(
                "Select foto from pacientes where id='" + (id) + "'");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        byte[] image = null;
        while (rs.next()) {
            image = rs.getBytes("foto");
        }
        Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(image);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
        jlFoto.setIcon(icon);
    }else {
            System.out.println("El paciente tiene foto pero no se puede cargar");
        }
}
```

---

Suponiendo que te funciona la inserción de los datos, sustituye este código en tu **botón guardar imagen**:

```
    imagen = new File(tfNombre.getText() + tfApellido1.getText() + ".png");
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(webcam.getIconWidth(),
            webcam.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(webcam.getImage(), 0, 0, webcam.getImageObserver());
    g2.dispose();
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("C:\\Users\\AMC\\Desktop\\foto.png"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al Guardar la foto");
    }
```

Ya me cuentas!

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, El archivo se crea bien, me lo guarda en la misma ruta donde tengo el .Jar, pero lo que quiero es saber como hacer un insert en la BD y luego poder visualizarla, ya que cuando cargue el historial de cada cliente, debe tener su foto asociada.

Comment: David, prueba esos códigos que te he puesto, si tienes problemas nos lo cuentas!

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero me da un puntero nulo en la primera línea de este código:  <code>String imagen = jlFoto.getIcon().toString();
                System.out.println("imagen: " + jlFoto.getIcon().toString());
                File file = new File(imagen);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(blob.setBinaryStream(1));
                oos.writeObject(imagen);
                oos.close();<code>

Comment: Pero que es lo que quieres hacer, Leer o escribir con ese código?

Comment: Quiero hacer ambas cosas, por un lado, añadirle la foto al histórico de un cliente y por otro lado, cuando quiera mostrar los datos y el histórico del cliente que se muestre la foto

Comment: añado código como actualización, de mi ActionPerformed de guardar()

Comment: David, Mira lo nuevo que he puesto.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda @Mekagenden pero, no me interesa guardar la ruta, me interesa guardar directamente la imagen en la BD, en todos lados me dicen esto, pero la clinica se va a conectar a un servidor remoto de BD y desde la aplicación trabajará remotamente, entonces imagino que para guardar las imagenes en una ruta, tendrá que subirse por FTP y demás... De ahí que quiera guardar la imagen directametne, también porque es posible que haya concurrencia a la hora de trabajar, haya varias personas trabajando sobre la misma aplicacion. He probado lo que me dices y se guarda en un directorio

Comment: eso no quiero, no se si me estoy explicando bien o no, necesito grabar la imagen en la bd(Cosa que creo que ya tengo) y luego poder mostrarla en mi aplicación en un label, jPanel o similar, junto a todos los datos del cliente, aquí es dodne tengo el problema, ya que al descargar la imagen de la BD se descarga con extension ".bin"

Comment: Como se llama tu jTable?

Comment: no tengo ningún un Jtable, quiero mostar la imagen en un panel o JLabel o similar, en este caso un JLabel se llama jlFoto

Comment: He cambiado bastante el código donde cargo la imagen del cliente, recopilando código de muchos sitios, ya he evitado que salten excepciones o salgan punteros nulos, pero no carga la imagen

Comment: Solucionado, adjunto la solución en mi pregunta

Comment: Me alegro, el que busca encuentra! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(blob.setBinaryStream(1));
oos.writeObject(imagen);
oos.close();
```

Esto no es una imagen, es la serialización de un objeto `BufferedImage`.

El `ObjectOutputStream` te va a hacer la serialización del objeto, pero aparte de los bytes en sí te va a incluir metainformación de la clase, otros atributos del objeto, etc. en el formato propio de la serialización de Java.

Si lees los datos de vuelta, debes deserializar de nuevo a `BufferedImage` y recuperarás el objeto.

Más normal es que leas el fichero como bytes, y escribas esos bytes directamente en el blob. Algo así como

```
InputStream fis = ... //leer imagen desde fichero, cámara, etc.
OutputStream os = blob.setBinaryStream(1);
byte datos[] = new byte[4096];
int bytesLeidos;
while ((bytesLeidos = fis.read(datos)) > 0) {
  os.write (datos, 0, bytesLeidos);
}
// Cerrar streams, limpieza, try - catchs....
```